# amazon linux で cron が失敗したときに、それを知れるようにしたい。

Tags: aws, unix, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-linux

ec2 の amazon linux に対して、 cron でバッチを実行しました。 `/var/log/cron` を見てみた結果、時折、このバッチは失敗している様子です。

```
Nov 13 16:35:01 ip-172-31-29-31 CROND[20056]: (ec2-user) CMD (/path/to/my/program)
Nov 13 16:35:10 ip-172-31-29-31 CROND[20222]: (CRON) EXEC FAILED (/usr/sbin/sendmail): No such file or directory
Nov 13 16:35:10 ip-172-31-29-31 CROND[20055]: (ec2-user) MAIL (mailed 75823 bytes of output but got status 0x0001#012)
```

さらにわかることは、バッチが異常終了した際に、 cron はメールでもってそれを通知しようとしているが、 `sendmail` プログラムがないために、その処理は失敗している模様です。

#### 質問

- amazon linux での cron バッチ処理が失敗した場合に、それを知りたいと思いました。これは、どうやったら実現できますでしょうか？
- またさらに、失敗した場合には、例えばその標準エラーをどこかに出力しておきたいな、と考えています。このようなことは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- cronジョブの登録時に、実行するコマンド出力を適当なファイルにリダイレクトする。

  ```
  # 標準出力とエラー出力の両方をログファイルにリダイレクト
  /path/to/cronjob.sh > /path/to/cronjob.log 2>&1
  ```
- cronジョブの登録時に`MAILTO`でメールアドレスを指定しておく。指定がなければcronを実行したユーザのローカルメールボックスに保存される(`mail`コマンドで確認)。
  (※成功時も含めて実行結果がメールで送信される)

  ```
  MAILTO=hoge@example.com
  0 1 * * 1-5 /path/to/cronjob.sh
  ```
- エラー時のみメール通知する[cronlog](https://github.com/kazuho/kaztools/blob/master/cronlog)というツールもあるようです。

Comment: 補足として、メールを利用する場合、 `sendmail` コマンドがサーバーにインストールされている必要があるっぽいです。 (ログからも分かる感じではあるけれども)